# Unable to infer complex closure return type with SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, xcode11

Following part 3 of Apple's tutorial on SwiftUI, [Handling User Input](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input), I get this error:

> Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate

I'm using the same code as the tutorial (even coping from the 'Complete' sample code doesn't resolve the error).

Does anyone have a cue what is going wrong here?

[image]

```
struct LandmarkRow: View {
    var landmark: Landmark

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            landmark.image(forSize: 50)
            Text(verbatim: landmark.name)
            Spacer()

            if landmark.isFavorite {
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                    .imageScale(.medium)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Regardless of the cause of the issue, how could you indeed add an explicit type to disambiguate here? What would the return type in such a case be?

--

**Update**

Apparently you should not continue with your result of the 2nd tutorial with the 3rd. Some things changed in between of the tutorials that is not documented in the tutorial. I've added the project files to Github so you can [check out the diff](https://github.com/teameh/Apple-SwiftUI-Tutorials-SampleCode/commit/de5d13f4bf72fe57ab31c7ea094414f794a44ba8#diff-3a2226d5793d4d66ab461e74ea1a9920R19).

It's better to start the 3rd tutorial fresh with a fresh download of the Project files of the [3rd tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The issue is not with the closure, but with the `isFavorite` property on landmark.

It is not declared on the `Landmark` type, and the compiler instead of showing the undeclared property error, unable to resolve the stacks build closure return type, so it shows and error there.

Great job Apple tutorial writers and even better one Xcode11 compiler.

**To fix:**

1. Declare `isFavorite` variable on the `Landmark` type.
2. Make sure you update the `landmarkData.json` for every landmark record with the `isFavorite = false` entry, otherwise the app will crash at runtime.

Comment: Check! I expected I could continue with my result from the previous tutorial but apprently they changed `landmarkData.json` and some classes in between the tutorials! Thanks.

Comment: See full diff here https://github.com/teameh/Apple-SwiftUI-Tutorials-SampleCode/commit/de5d13f4bf72fe57ab31c7ea094414f794a44ba8#diff-3a2226d5793d4d66ab461e74ea1a9920R19

Answer (score 6):

### Some background to this problem

Like @dirtydanee already answered there is a difference between those two tutorials. But the problem behind the problem is that while it looks like you're doing a configuration it's actually just functions nested in functions using generics and protocols to "magically" parse everything into a compiling function.

However conformance to these generics and protocols need to be pretty precise because if not the whole tree of functions cannot compile anymore. But it's hard to determine for the compiler what conformance actually failed. This is why you see an error at the top rather than at the point where it actually happens.

It's strongly advised to make sure your views are decomposed into natural and simple blocks so you're not pouring over hundreds of lines of `View` code to find that one bug.

[Dave DeLong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115730/dave-delong) had [a really great talk](https://vimeo.com/291601827) about how to compose Views from ViewControllers that still holds true until today: basically you never use View as a subview inside another View but you need to decompose your View of many, simple Views. Otherwise these errors'll drive you nuts.

Comment: As a newcomer to swift and the swift ecosystem, this still seems very unfriendly.
I started looking into Swift because of SwiftUI and the error messages that the SwiftUI declaration give are very unreadable and not understandable at all. Mistakes lines away where you have the mistake (missing argument name for me most often) is very frustrating.

Comment: Yeah but the error messages have always been improving, it’s so much better in terms of compiler feedback and usefulness of error messages than Swift 1.0. That was really rough.

Answer (score 2):

**For people getting this error on SwiftUI and looking for a way to debug their view stack**

This error happens mainly when there is a compilation issue on one child View.

1 - Make sure your parent view can support multiple subviews (VStack, ZStack) and you have less than 10 subviews. Sometime you may want to add a Group wrapper.

2 - If this is not the problem, there is probably an issue with one subview. Try to isolate the one you suspect to have the issue. Usually I copy the subview into a property and a different error appears

```
var debug: some View {
        MyViewWithError(property: self.property)
}
```

Most of the time you'll encounter this because you pass the property (`self.property`) instead of a binding (`self.$property`)

Hope this can help some people

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this error when made a typo. Also this error appears when a code has syntax issues. Just check if your changes are correct

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the problem in a subview where a @Binding prop was of a different type of the @Binding source.