# Swift compiler issue when running Xcode 11 using SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to get my `SwiftUI` Demo running but I get weird compiler issues:

> 'Color' is not convertible to 'Color?'
>
> Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate

```swift
struct LandmarkRow: View {
  var landmark: Landmark
    
  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      landmark.image(forSize: 50)
      Text(landmark.name)
      Spacer()
    
      if landmark.isFavorite {
        Image(systemName: "star.fill")
           .imageScale(.medium)
           .foregroundColor(.yellow) // Here 'Color' is not convertible to 'Color?'
      }
    }
  }
}

struct LandmarkList: View {
  @State var showFavoritesOnly = true
    
  var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
          List {
              Toggle(isOn: $showFavoritesOnly) {
                  Text("Favorites only")
              }
    
              ForEach(landmarkData) { landmark in // Here Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate
                  if !self.showFavoritesOnly || landmark.isFavorite {
                      NavigationButton(destination: LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)) {
                          LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
                      }
                  }
              }
              .navigationBarTitle(Text("Landmarks"))
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I was also following the tutorial and ran into the same issue on that line. This appears to be a bug in the Xcode beta.

Comment: You cannot continue with your results from tutorial 2 without making some changes before you start with tutorial 3 
https://github.com/teameh/Apple-SwiftUI-Tutorials-SampleCode/commit/de5d13f4bf72fe57ab31c7ea094414f794a44ba8#diff-3a2226d5793d4d66ab461e74ea1a9920R19

It's better to download their sample code for tutorial 3 and continue with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well... This is related to the `isFavorite` property it's missing in the Landmark file. (It's missing ‍♂️)

So I'm going to fill a bug about this bad compiler message. This is definitely a bug. The radar number `FB6118410`

If you want to fix it you need to do 2 things:
1

1. Add this to the `Landmark` struct `var isFavorite: Bool`
2. You need to edit the `landmarkData.json` and add this key and value         `"isFavorite":  true` otherwise it will crash.

Comment: Spurious errors (like the `Color?` one really being caused by malformed JSON) in SwiftUI are driving me nuts.

Comment: I know this is kind of dumb, but make sure when you add to your .json file you putt a comma before the previous line.

Comment: I also just ran into a bug where "isFavorite" _was_ in the JSON and the Landmark code, however, I needed to restart xcode before it realised I'd added the isFavorite attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the Swift compiler is generating error messages which can be some distance from where the actual problem is located. We are being encouraged to file radars on such issues.

In this instance, I can see you are missing the `verbatim:` parameter name on creating the first `Text()`:

```
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            landmark.image(forSize: 50)
            Text(verbatim: landmark.name) // don't forget the "verbatim" parameter name
            Spacer()

            if landmark.isFavorite {
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                    .imageScale(.medium)
                    .foregroundColor(.yellow)
            }
        }
    }
```

...however I was not able to reproduce the compiler error you are seeing by removing this. I would therefore recommend carefully diffing against the completed project files which you can download from the tutorial page.

Edit: looks like someone else had the same issue - you can find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56451329/233602 (check the `isFavourite` property on Landmark).