# Getting the error "Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate" when trying to recreate the SwiftUI List demo

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to recreate the SwiftUI demo with a difference being I want to use my own object `Item`.

Item:

```
class Item {

    var company: String = ""
    var item_class: String = ""
    var name: String = ""
    var stock: Int = 0
    var average_cost: Decimal = 0.00
    var otc_price: Decimal = 0.00
    var dealer_price: Decimal = 0.00
    var ctc_price: Decimal = 0.00

    class var _API_LIST_EP: String {return "api/inventory/items/"}

    // Init and Funcs
    // JToken is an extended typealias for [String : Any] that makes parsing easier
    required init(_ jt: JToken) {
        company = jt.string(forKey: "company")
        item_class = jt.string(forKey: "item_class")
        name = jt.string(forKey: "name")
        stock = jt.int(forKey: "stock")
        average_cost = jt.decimal(forKey: "average_cost")
        otc_price = jt.decimal(forKey: "otc_price")
        dealer_price = jt.decimal(forKey: "dealer_price")
        ctc_price = jt.decimal(forKey: "ctc_price")
    }

}
```

In a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56450789/unable-to-infer-complex-closure-return-type-with-swiftui), it was noted that the issue stemmed from one of the object's variables being initialized in an ambiguous state however after filling up all of my object's variables, it still comes up

Problematic code:

```
struct ContentView : View {

    var itemList: [Item] = []
    var body: some View {
        List(itemList) { item in
            Image(systemName: "photo")
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(item.name)
                Text(item.company)
                .font(.subheadline)
                .color(.gray)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot of the error:

[image: Error Code]

Comment: Please post the problematic code as *code,* not as a screenshot.

Comment: Apologies, will do!

Comment: I also wonder how you can have a `override class var`  and `super.init()` if the class does not inherit from a superclass. – As always, a [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: My mistake, I tried a solution and instead of cleaning it up first before posting it here, I did the reverse. I just did a passthrough and it should be good now

Comment: `Item` must conform to `Identifiable` ...

Comment: Thank you Martin, that solved the issue! Could you submit an answer so I can designate it as such?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is misleading.

```
List(itemList) { item in ... }
```

requires that the element type of `itemList` conforms to the `Identifiable` protocol. For *classes* (as in your case) it is sufficient to declare protocol conformance

```
class Item: Identifiable {
   // ...
}
```

because there is a default implementation (based on the object identifier).